# Symfony post data should not be null in request->get()

Tags: forms, symfony, request, xmlhttprequest, postdata

I have extra field on my form. This extra field not use Symfony Form.
I want to get values of this extra field in my controller.

Twig code :

```
{% for module in tool.modules %}
       <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="user_access_{{ tool.id }}_{{ module.id }}" name="user[access_{{ tool.id }}][]" value="{{ module.id }}">                                                                                  
   <label for="user_access_{{ tool.id }}_{{ module.id }}">{{ module.name }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Controller code :

```
    /**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editUser(Request $request, User $user, ModuleRepository $moduleRepository): Response
{
    //some code

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array('user'=>$user, 'category'=>$categ, 'tools'=>$tools));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        dd($request); // parameter access_278 contains data I want
        dd($request->request->get('user[access_278][]')); // GET NULL :(
```

[Results of dd($request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezAAa.png)

(The values I want is for access_278)

As you can see on the results pic, the request contains the data of access_278.

Why in : ***dd($request->request->get('user[access_278][]'))*** I get "null" when I should get the values of the checkboxes?

Maybe I am using a wrong way to retrieve the data?

Comment: well you're accessing it wrong. There is **no** key `user[access_278][]` in $request->request. I'm not sure if symfony can handle "dot-notation" like `->request('user.access_278')`. If no, you have to grab all data and access it like an array. 
`$userPostData = $request->reqeust->get('user'); dd($userPostData['access_278']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the property in a bad way. Try this instead:

```
$request->get("user['access_278']");
```